How to ensure specific variables are included in rlassoEffect using the hdm package in R?
I'm trying to perform post-Lasso regression using the rlassoEffect function from the hdm package in R. I want to make sure that certain control variables are always included in the model, but I'm not sure how to do this.
Here's a minimal example that demonstrates what I'm trying to do:
library(hdm)
library(plm) 

# Example minimal dataset
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  id = rep(1:5, each = 4),
  time = rep(1:4, times = 5),
  y = rnorm(20),
  d = rnorm(20) + 1,
  x1 = rnorm(20),
  x2 = rnorm(20)
)

df$x3 <- df$d + rnorm(20, mean = 0, sd = 0.5) # Adjusted to be correlated with d

df_p <- pdata.frame(df, index = c("id", "time"))

# Minimum example code
vX = as.matrix(subset(df_p, select = c("x1", "x2", "x3")))
vy <- as.numeric(df_p$y)
vd <- as.numeric((df_p$d))

viol_dblslct <- rlassoEffect(x = vX, y = vy, d = vd, method = "double selection", post = TRUE, included = ~ time, data = df_p)
viol_dblslct[["selection.index"]]  


In the example above, I want to ensure that dummy variables for all the time periods minus 1 are  always included in the regressions. The output for 'viol_dblslct[["selection.index"]]' shows that the time controls have not been included. One can also see that rlassoEffect is working correctly because it included x3 in the estimation. See picture below.
selection_index
Is there a way to ensure that the time dummies are included in the regression?
